# How to give permission to access phone Addressbook in ios 10.0?

Tags: ios10, xcode8

> This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain an NSContactsUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

I added to the .plist `NSContactsUsageDescription`

**doesn't work  -  device version:10.0**

```
KTSContactsManager *addressBookManager = [KTSContactsManager sharedManager];
addressBookManager.delegate = self;
addressBookManager.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"firstName" ascending:YES]];

if ([isAddressBookTaken isEqualToString:@"false"]) {
    [addressBookManager importContacts:^(NSArray *contacts) {
        [EBLogger logWithTag:@"TBLContactManager" withBody:@"importContacts"];

        DLPhoneBook *phoneBook = [DLPhoneBook new];
        NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [NSMutableArray new];

        for (int i = 0; i < contacts.count; ++i) {
            NSDictionary *record = [contacts objectAtIndex:i];
            NSError *err = nil;
            DLContactRecord *contactRecord = [[DLContactRecord alloc] initWithDictionary:record error:&err];

            NSLog(@" %@ %@ %@ '",contactRecord.firstName, contactRecord.lastName, contactRecord.id);
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add information list in your plist,

[image: information plist]

Here is information plist for various privacy.

Add Privacy that you want in you plist and check again.

and ADD this code in your file,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    contactList=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    ABAddressBookRef m_addressbook = ABAddressBookCreate();

    if (!m_addressbook) {
        NSLog(@"opening address book");
    }

    CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(m_addressbook);
    CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(m_addressbook);

    for (int i=0;i &lt; nPeople;i++) { 
        NSMutableDictionary *dOfPerson=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

        ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople,i);

        //For username and surname
        ABMultiValueRef phones =(NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
        CFStringRef firstName, lastName;
        firstName = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
        lastName  = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
        [dOfPerson setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName] forKey:@"name"];

        //For Email ids
        ABMutableMultiValueRef eMail  = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonEmailProperty);
        if(ABMultiValueGetCount(eMail) &gt; 0) {
            [dOfPerson setObject:(NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(eMail, 0) forKey:@"email"];

        }

        //For Phone number
        NSString* mobileLabel;
        for(CFIndex i = 0; i &lt; ABMultiValueGetCount(phones); i++) {
            mobileLabel = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phones, i);
            if([mobileLabel isEqualToString:(NSString *)kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel])
            {
                [dOfPerson setObject:(NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, i) forKey:@"Phone"];
            }
            else if ([mobileLabel isEqualToString:(NSString*)kABPersonPhoneIPhoneLabel])
            {
                [dOfPerson setObject:(NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, i) forKey:@"Phone"];
                break ;
            }

        [contactList addObject:dOfPerson];
        CFRelease(ref);
        CFRelease(firstName);
        CFRelease(lastName);
    }
    NSLog(@"array is %@",contactList);
    }
}
```

For more about it visit,

http://sugartin.info/2011/09/07/get-information-from-iphone-address-book-in-contacts/

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Hi @KAR thanks for your answer, I did what you've explained, but I keep getting the same error. I also remove app and drived data file.

Comment: check this link if its useful to you, https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/62229

Comment: + Settings > MyApp >  "Contacts" does not appearance !